# Using _count in a select query with Prisma

Tags: sql, typescript, prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm currently undergoing a rewrite of my Discord bot, and in this process I need to rewrite all of my SQL queries and convert them into Prisma queries.

SQL query I', trying to convert into Prisma:
`connection.query('SELECT inviterId, count(*) as count FROM invites where serverId = ? AND valid = 1 GROUP BY inviterId ORDER BY count DESC')`

I currently have this:

```
    let leaderboard = await client.prisma.invites.aggregate({
      _count: {
        inviterId: true,
      },
      where: {
        serverId: message.guildID,
        valid: true,
      },
      orderBy: {
        inviterId: "desc",
      }
    });
    console.log(leaderboard);
```

This returns: `{ _count: { inviterId: 25 } }`

However, I need to also return the data in a select query. As far as I know it is not possible to use _count in a findMany query, so I tried to use select in an aggregate query, but that doesn't work either.

I am unsure how I can select the data to be returned, and sorted by largest count. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of aggregate, you need to use the groupBy API.

Taken from Prisma docs:
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/aggregation-grouping-summarizing

```
const groupUsers = await prisma.user.groupBy({
  by: ['country'],
  _sum: {
    profileViews: true,
  },
})
```